# jQuery .mousemove() with :hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mousemove

I'm trying to write a simple hover preview effect. I'm using the CSS :hover pseudo class to make the larger image appear, and jQuery .mousemove() to track the position of the mouse cursor. The larger image is supposed to appear on hover and follow the mouse cursor.

The problem is that the larger image does not disappear when the mouse is no longer "hover". It will follow the mouse all over the page for a few seconds before finally going away. It seems to work a little better in IE8, but not in any other browser (IE8 is also giving me positioning problems, but that's a different issue).

Any help would be appreciated.

[Here's the code](http://jsfiddle.net/nP8zh/17/):

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jF27b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a little more padding in your offset so that the mouse isn't hovering over the large image. Check out this [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/YKq4F/)

```
 var relX = pageX - parentOffset.left +20;
 var relY = pageY - parentOffset.top+20;
```

Comment: +20 still seemed a little wonky, so I used +40, and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the hover effect just does not catch up with mouse movements fast enough.  Instead of relying purely on `:hover`, what you may need to do is have a `.mouseout` callback that has a timeout (some sane amount .. probably 500) to remove the image, and a `.mouseover` that resets the timeout (you can store the timeout on `.data` of the hovered image -- the image with the callback).

I haven't delved into your code, but here is some pseudo-code to explain what I mean

```
$(".big-img-that-follows-mouse").mouseout(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   //You can also .hide() or whatever instead of .remove()
   $this.data('timeout', setTimeout(function () { $this.remove(); }), 500));
})
.mouseover(function () {
   if ($(this).data('timer') {
      clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
      $(this).removeData('timer');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at what this guy has done here:

Example: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/
Code: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/main.js

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if you'd formatted your HTML instead of dumping it into jsfiddle in one long string.

Anyway your problem is that your large image is nested inside of your list so that when you're hovering it you're also still hovering your original item.